# Error "collectstatic --noinput" in heroku with Github

Tags: python, django, github, heroku

I have created and worked on a Django application (Simple website with user registration and login) and now i want to try deploying it into Heroku. I have already uploaded my full code to GitHub and I am using the deployment method through GitHub on Heroku. I connected my GitHub directory to Heroku and started the deployment, but an error came up. I have searched everywhere but I can't find a solution anywhere.

**Error:**

```
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
           self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
           output = self.handle(*args, **options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 188, in handle
           collected = self.collect()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 105, in collect
           for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 125, in list
           for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 23, in get_files
           directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 313, in listdir
           for entry in os.listdir(path):
       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_e6d59abe7139c45ae94e60de651b660c/sitoassociazione/static'
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

**setting.py:**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1',]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'users',
    'pages',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sitoassociazione.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sitoassociazione.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static').replace('\\','/'),
                    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
                    )
```

**manage.py:**

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sitoassociazione.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

**project structure:**

```
sitoassociazione
[
[-pages
[   [-migrations
[   [   [-<<migration files>>
[   [-static
[   [   [-css
[   [      [-main.css
[   [   
[   [-templates
[   [   [-<<templates files>>
[   [   
[   [<<other files>>
[
[-sitoassociazione
[   [-_pycache_ (folder)
[   [-_init_.py
[   [-.DS_Store
[   [-settings.py
[   [urls.py
[   [wsgi.py
[-users
```

Sorry for so much text but it's my first Stackoverflow question and so i don't know all the tips and tricks to use it.

Comment: You probably want to edit your post so that your SECRET_KEY isn't visible, or at least you post a different value from the real one. (Perhaps it already is, but it's safer to check.) Or change your production SECRET_KEY before you deploy it. As for the error, did you try what it says, setting DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC to 1?

Comment: @RobinZigmond please don't recommend that, OP clearly does want the static files to be collected.

Comment: It's not the source of your error, but this: `.replace('\\','/')` in your STATICFILES_DIRS is nonsense; you should remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I resolved by putting the same exact static folder i had in my pages app, in my sitoassociazione app and also in the main sitoassociazione folder